# php laravel ->status check button's value does not go to database (always stays 0)

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, if-statement

**Hello, I have an adminController as below. Even though I checked the status box, it comes to the database as zero. I can't figure out why if/else block doesn't work. If I use debug i can see "on" value for checkbox**

```
public function addPost(Request $request){

    $name=$request->title;
    $content=$request->content;
    $status=$request->status;

    if(!is_null($status)){
        $status=0;
    }
    else{
        $status=1;
    }

    Posts::create([
        'name' =>$name,
        'content' =>$content,
        'status' =>$status
    ]);
}
```

**addPost.php (it's my form)**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">
        <input type="checkbox" name="status" id="status">Status
    </label>
</div>
```

[image: form image]
[image: mysql]

Comment: Normally you test for the existance of a checkbox in $_POST to indicate it was checked or not.

Comment: So try `if(!isset($status)){ $status=0;  } else{ $status=1; }`

Comment: `Log::info($request->all());` and then check the log in `storage/logs`, to see what the request contains and what `status` contains. You might have better luck with `$status = $request->status ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: can you please share your migration

Comment: public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->tinyInteger('status')->default(0);
        });
    }     @RachnaGajjar

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work  @aynber

Comment: What do you see in the log file with the logging information I gave?

Comment: Np didn't work:/ @RiggsFolly

Comment: it gives an error that it can't find the log page @aynber

Comment: It takes the default 0 in migration, so I interpret it as not reading the value at all.

Comment: `storage/logs` is in the project root, it's not a webpage that you go to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you are checking the !is_null on the code, because of which you are getting the 0 if you are checking the checkbox, the condition should be like this:

```
if(is_null($status)){
     $status=0;
}
else{
     $status=1;
}
```

if you are still confused about this then pass a value from the checkbox and check that value in the controller:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">
        <input type="checkbox" name="status" id="status" value="1">Status
    </label>
</div>
```

Now, you can check like this in the controller:

```
if(isset($status) && $status == 1){
         $status=1;
    }
    else{
         $status=0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you a little bit change:

```
public function addPost(Request $request){

    $name=$request->title;
    $content=$request->content;
   

    //if box is checked status will be 1
    if($request->status){
        $status=1;
    }
    //if box is unchecked status will be 0
    else{
        $status=0;
    }

    Posts::create([
        'name' =>$name,
        'content' =>$content,
        'status' =>$status
    ]);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: did you try with status column default value null in database?

Answer (score 0):

> First problem is  **if(!is_null($status))** it is never null because
> you can write in your migration default(0) so here we can manage with
> Controller.

```
  if($status == 0)
   {
     $status=1;
   }
```

> here status is default 0 so we check $status == 0 then we have to change it to 1 and if this condition is false then status value is already 1.

Comment: @Aleyna Şenozan i hope you got correct answer.